# Selecting the row before and after the value changes in one column and correlate with the change in value in next column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following problem that I am trying to solve using SQL server 2008.

The table has 4 columns
1- Identifier such as (a,a,a,b,b,c,c)
2- Time (in seconds)
3- Value 1 (integer)
4- Value 2 (Float)

When sorted by time for each identifier the Value 1 is repeated for several rows. Once the Value 1 changes there is a corresponding change in Value 2 after several rows (ranging between 1 and 5+ seconds).

1- Detect when the Value 1 changes and correspond it to when Value 2 changes
2- Difference in seconds between Value 1 changes.

I cannot use Partition by because there are recurring values for Value 1 and Value 2.

```
Identifier  TimeStamp   Value1  Value2
a           12:10:01      2      0.98
a           12:10:02      2      0.98
a           12:10:03      3      0.98
a           12:10:05      2      0.98
a           12:10:06      3      0.50
a           12:10:09      2      0.98
a           12:10:12      2      0.50
a           12:10:13      2      0.98
b           12:10:10      2      0.98
b           12:10:11      4      0.98
b           12:10:12      5      0.98
b           12:10:12      5      0.80
b           12:10:12      5      1.20
```

I have been trying the following query but it is taking too long to run. For every change in Value1 there is a corresponding change in Value2. The change in value 2 can happen any time over the period of several seconds. I cannot figure out a way to correlate the two changes.

;WITH Value1Change AS (
SELECT
     ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp) AS [RNum]
     ,Identifier
     ,T1.[TimeStamp] AS [T1 TimeStamp]
     ,T2.[TimeStamp] AS [T2 TimeStamp]
     ,T1.[Value1] AS [T1_Value 1]
     ,T2.[Value2] AS [T2_Value 1]

FROM Table T1
INNER JOIN Table T2 ON T1.[Identifier]=T2.[Identifier] AND T1.RNum=T2.RNum+1
WHERE T2.[Value1]<>T1.[Value1]
)

SELECT
      VC1.Identifier
      ,VC1.[T2 TimeStamp]
      ,VC2.[T2 TimeStamp]
      ,DATEDIFF(S,VC1.[T2 TimeStamp],VC2.[T2 TimeStamp]) AS [Time Between Change]
      ,VC1.[T1_Value 1]
      ,VC1.[T2_Value 1]

FROM ValueChange VC1
INNER JOIN ValueChange VC2 ON VC1.Unit=VC2.Unit AND VC1.RNum=VC2.RNum+1
ORDER BY VC1.RNum

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: I have edited my original post to include a sample table and my query.

Comment: see the link referenced to know on , how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/